# Magento "Headers already sent" after Upgrade

Tags: javascript, magento, templates, header, upgrade

I've searched the web for days but can't find a solution. I upgraded Magento from 1.5 to 1.9 and everything works fine. Except the checkout. On the last step it gets stuck every single time on "submitting order information".

System log says the following (but a minute before the error occurs. In the stuck position I don't get any error)

```
    2016-08-07T22:23:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0]    /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/index.php:83</pre>
```

Console on the checkout site:

```
    VK. Startup (background is ready)
prototype.js:5557 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined_createResponder @ prototype.js:5557observe @ prototype.js:5636(anonymous function) @ (index):896
prototype.js:5557 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined_createResponder @ prototype.js:5557observe @ prototype.js:5636(anonymous function) @ (index):1033
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.owndomain.com/checkout/onepage/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
content.js:37 UA. Wait for background...
```

Does anybody have an additional idea? I have edited all template files with the formkey tag.

Edit:

The code of the found file:

```
  if (empty ($_POST)) {
        header("Location: " . $_SESSION['back_url']);
        $this->_redirect(str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl(), '', $_SESSION['back_url']));

    }
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('super_attribute');
    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('pro_id');
    $options = $this->getRequest()->getPost('options');
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    //mage::log($params);
    $url = $this->getRequest()->getPost('url');
    $qty = $this->getRequest()->getPost('qty');
    $type = $this->getRequest()->getPost('type');
    if (!isset($qty))
        $qty = 1;
    if (isset($product_id)) {
        try {
            $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
            $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
            /*
            if (isset($formData)){
                $arr = array(
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'super_attribute' => $formData,
                    'options'    => $options
                );
                $cart->addProduct($product, $arr);}
            else
                $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
            */
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $session->setLastAddedProductId($product->getId());
            $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            $cart->save();
            $_cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
            $_cartcount = 0;
            $_cartsubtotal = 0;
            $items = $_cart->getItems();
            $_SESSION['back_url'] = $url;
            $result = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('ajaxcart/cart/sidebar.phtml')
                ->addItemRender('simple', 'checkout/cart_item_renderer', 'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')
                ->addItemRender('configurable', 'checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable', 'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')
                ->addItemRender('grouped', 'checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped', 'checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
            echo $result;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 1;
        }
    } else {
        echo 0;
```

Best,
IT0055

Comment: Do you have any customized code or extensions that do 'echo' or other weird methods of output? If, for example, an extension listen to checkout event and do stuff with echo it might cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found indeed an old extension with this code in a file called "Frontcontroller.php" which als causes errors with "undefined index in "back_url". Do you have an idea what to do with this code? (In my last edit)

Comment: echo result in controller is wrong way for sending response. Use $this->getResponse()->setBody($result); return; to send response. This will resolve header already sent issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I make you the answer now?